# How to trigger an event after loading the page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I think this is very easy, but i dont know how to do it.
I have some pictures with a click event that when is clicked, it open a light box but i want to activate the click when the page is open like when is recieving a id from the link (i.e. www.somelink.com/?id=2).

this link that should active when is recieve the id on the URL

bla bla

Is this possible?

Comment: What server side technology are you using? PHP, ASP/.NET?

Comment: better first do it in PHP, making it work without JS. Then add JS to the solution which activates the light box features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's possible.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( ) { jQuery(selector).click( ); } );
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

You'll need to create a hidden element on your page to pass the `id` in to, if that's needed for the selector.

Comment: the .click() event isnt suppose to work when is clicked? like if the selector is clicked do this??

Comment: @macieira `jQuery(selector).click()` is equivalent to `jQuery(selector).trigger('click')`. With an argument, `.click()` sets the handler, and without one it calls the handler. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfTheElement').trigger('click');
});
```

**Note:**

If you only want to do this when you get the id parameter from the query string, you must wrap the code I posted in an if statement.

Comment: Thanks. I was in the right way. i saw the trigger event but thought the event work like the .click event.

Comment: `$_GET = <?php echo $_GET['l']?>;
 
if($_GET != ''){
    $('img[name*="album'+$_GET+'"]').trigger("click");
}`

Comment: @macieria Nice. :)
If it worked for you, try to mark the answer as accepted (under the vote up/down buttons) so other people can do the same you did if they have the same question.

Comment: @macieira btw, it's been a while since I developed in PHP, but I think that assigning a value to $_GET may give some troubles. Try to use a different variable for this.